I need help excecuting FFT on huge numbers
I'm designing a circuit that needs to run FFT on very large numbers (as large as a few megabytes, stored in storage as any reasonable register length you think will be best). I want to run FFT on this number as a way to multiply them.
How can I do this with absolute accuracy (so no floating point numbers), and in general with the lowest number of non-integers possible?

As written, you're basically asking us to do the whole thing for you, which isn't what Stack Overflow is for. Please see: Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question? Also, this question is about hardware design, not programming.

You basically have two choices:

Do the FFT in floating point, with enough precision to guarantee that the results will be accurate when you round them to integers.
Use a number theoretic transform instead of an FFT.  This replaces the complex numbers with integer remainders of a prime modulus.


I researched NTT for a bit and it seems like a move in the right direction. The problem is finding a prime. I don't have enough storage for a list of primes long enough for my use case and trying to find them every time seems really wasteful

You only need one prime.  It just needs to be big enough for your largest input, and (p-1) needs a large enough factor of 2^x to do it FFT-style. https://cp4space.hatsya.com/2021/09/01/an-efficient-prime-for-number-theoretic-transforms/

"the" or "a"?...
